# how to set session value as quarry set object

Tags: python, django

**here is my code**

```
b = student_details.objects.all()
request.session["b"] = b
```

**its giving me error**

```
TypeError at /logs
Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

i want to fetch all data form student_details table and show it on display.html page

```
def login(request):
    if request.session.has_key("b"):
        b = request.session['b']
        return render(request,'display.html', {"b":b})
```

its showing me above error

Comment: You can't store a `QuerySet`, since the session is stored as a JSON blob.

Comment: any other option is their to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you should convert queryset to list and json.dumps
like this

```py
b = student_details.objects.all()
b = list(b)
import json
b = json.dumps(b)
```

Make sure there are basic data structures in it.